# Dynamically pass name from table to function define

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, mysql2

In my mysql database there are several tables with the same name.
table_1, table_2, table_3, ..., table_n

All these tables have exactly the same structure, I would like to pass to the define function of sequelize just this parameter to make it dynamic, is there a way to do this?

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const connection = require("./database");

const Table = connection.define('table_1', {
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    }
}, { timestamps: false, freezeTableName: true });


module.exports = Weather;
```

As I said, all tables contain the same structure and the same name, differentiating only the number after the underline.

Could someone solve this dynamically?
Thanks

Comment: Where does the `Weather` come from? Do you want to dynamically create table_1, table_2, table_3, ..., table_n? If so, why don't use `for-loop`?